# catch restrict mm to greater than 59 hh:mm

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime

I am trying to restrict user to enter greater than 59 value. But when user entering value in MM it is not triggering in any event to catch value. I tried with vanilla js and rxjs too.You will able to see when you remove focus from input it will automatically set to 59.

[image]

code:

```
 @ViewChild('value', {static: false}) timeValue: ElementRef;

  onInput(event: Event) {
    // console.log((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    fromEvent(this.timeValue.nativeElement, 'keypress').subscribe((value: Event) => {
      console.log((value.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
    })
  }
```

**Playground:** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3qv9sx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: The playground is working correct for me, if I start with a number greater than 5 it focus in the next input value, which browser are you using?

Comment: Do not use arrow up down to change time try to enter in input field with keypad, btw I am using chrome Version 80.0.3987.149

Comment: For me it still works correctly and I try with the same browser that you. I am using keypad to set the input, and it is checking time just fine. Now that I realize there might be an issue with locale, it is showing to me the option of AM/PM, that you don't have in the capture. What is your locale?.

Comment: india, navigator.language "en-US, are you not able to enter greater than 59 in mm after : ?

Comment: Exactly, for me it is working correct, i also have en-US. I will add you a screen capture.

Answer (score 0):

Add screen capture of my test using the playground. The only thing I change was deleting the text and add the language of the navigator, just in case.

[image: Screen capture Chrome Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit)]

Comment: Do you get any event you change mm in time ?